# Tuple type in Snowflake my_var

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can I create a tuple in Snowflake.

> set my_var = (1,2,3);
>
> select * from mytable where user_id IN $my_var;
>
> Should select users with IDs 1,2,3

Where Type($my_var) will give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, tuples are not a data type within Snowflake.  Your set command will result in an error as the number of assignment variables does not equal the number of assignment values.

If you have a Snowflake account I suggest looking into using the variant or array data types and their functions, then trying your code before asking the question.

Comment: As a solution to your original question, you can do the following:
```set my_var = '[1,2,3]'

select * from mytable where array_contains(user_id,parse_json($my_var));
```